# Horizontal clip not working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, effect, clip

I'm trying to make a clip effect with jQuery I have this:

```
$("#citywrap").show("clip", {directional: "horizontalL"}, 1000);
```

but the clip only goes horizontal and I need my image appear from left, not as slide. Just as if it got drawn.

http://khronosmx.com/

that site is the example when you click de circle, all the rest of things appear but my city shows with the horizontal clip effect, i need to make it from left to right.

Comment: No, is just jquery working.

Comment: oh! This is jQuery UI, right? If so, you may want to add that tag.

Answer (score 0):

I reach it putting a div over the image and remove that div with

```
$("#cityblank").hide("slide",{direction: "right"}, 3000);

<div id="citywrap"><div id="cityblank"></div><img src="assets/ciudad_vector.png" style="position:absolute; width:100%; z-index:-10;"></div>
```

but now the problem is that this doesn't run on cellphones.